# Adventure that introduced "banks" that cost money to store items

Tags: product-identification, adnd-1e

When I was a young child (around the mid 1980s to the mid 1990s), I read a number of AD&D modules, albeit without much of a chance to actually play them. Recently, when reading the TV Tropes entry for [In-Game Banking Services](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InGameBankingServices), I was suddenly reminded of reading a module that had a set of available bank vaults for players to store their valuable items and currency, or for them to attempt to plunder the vaults. At the time, I remember being baffled at the idea of paying to store money, growing up with modern banking where the banks make money on interest from loaning out the money being kept with them, allowing them to pay interest for people keeping money with them. Of course, my parents explained that what the banks in the module were providing was security, noting that the module also detailed traps and guards on the vaults (which would come into play if the players decided to try to loot the vaults). I think it was a relatively low-level adventure module, in the single digits, with the guards basically being level 3, and considered to be a viable threat to the party.

I unfortunately have forgotten some details over the years, but I think there were 6-8 vaults available, some of which were empty (available to the players, or to provide the "fun" situation of players wasting time and resources breaking into a vault that has nothing on it). I don't remember the details of the traps, but I mainly remember them being alarms (to bring guards) and things like poison needles and crossbows rigged to fire at the door if not disarmed rather than content-breaking traps like falling slabs or flooding the vaults.

My apologies if this is a more common trope than I'm thinking. I only remember running into it the once, and it's occasionally come back to me when encountering tabletop and video games where banking is free, or even provides interest income like modern banks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **LOAN BANK** [*sic*] is location 11 of TSR's Dungeon Module B2: [***The Keep on the Borderlands***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Keep_on_the_Borderlands) (1982). The description, in part, says

> Here anyone can change money or gems for a 10% fee. The banker will also keep a person’s wealth stored safely at no charge if it is left for at least one month, otherwise there is a 10% fee.… The strong room of the place is in the cellar. It is protected by a locked iron door which leads to a small vault with 12 compartments each protected by lock…. (9)

And there are deadly traps everywhere—*seriously* deadly and *seriously* everywhere. There are guards, too: two in plate mail, but each level 1 not 3. And a wizard, too.

I ran the *Keep* a few years ago and my normally all-content-must-be-mine players decided against the whole rob-the-bank thing. A rich target, sure, but alienate the only trading post for, like, hundreds of miles? Not even they were that brave.

Comment: That's one I remember reading, one of the classics. I'll check into it when I'm off work, but that sounds very promising.